# Pandas Dataframe filter not working but str.match() is working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe `words_df` which contains some English words.

It only has one column named `word` which contains the English word.

`words_df.tail()`:

[image]

`words_df.dtypes`:

[image]

I want to filter out the row(s) which contain the word **zythum**

Using the Pandas Series `str.match()` is giving me expected output:

`words_df[words_df.word.str.match('zythum')]`:

I know `str.match()` is not the correct way to do it, it will also return rows which contain other words like **zythums** for example.

[image]

But, using the following operation on Pandas Dataframe is returning an empty Dataframe

`words_df[words_df['word'] == 'zythum']`:

[image]

I was wondering why is this happening?

EDIT 1:
I am also attaching the source of my data and the code used to import it.

Data source (I used **"Word lists in csv.zip"**):

https://www.bragitoff.com/2016/03/english-dictionary-in-csv-format/

Dataframe import code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob as glob
import os as os
import csv

path = r'data/words/' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=None, names = ['word'], engine='python', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    li.append(df)

words_df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

EDIT 2:

Here is a block of my code, with a simpler import code, but facing same issue. (using **Zword.csv** file from link mentioned above)
[image]

Comment: I have just tried to recreate this but they have both produced the same result of outputting that one row.

Comment: I have added the source to data and the code used to import the data, if that helps you. @DavidBuck

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in the import code that isn't needed just to download the dictionary.csv. Could you cut it down to the simplest code that will read dictionary.csv and create a dataframe that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: I have added a simpler import code to demonstrate my problem. I am still facing the same issue. @DavidBuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC: `df1[df1['word'] == 'zythum']` is not working.

Try, removing whitespace around the string in the dataframe:

```
 df1[df1['word'].str.strip() == 'zythum']
```

Comment: This is not my objective.
I want to filter rows with word 'zythum'.
I am wondering why `words_df[words_df['word'] == 'zythum']` is not working for me.

Comment: @lazygeek Ah... okay.

Comment: Seems the data has trailing spaces.
This was a stupid question, Do I need to delete this question before the good ppl over here start downvoting this question?

Answer (score 1):

Your imported list does not match the string you are looking for exactly. There is a space after the words in the csv file.

You should be able to strip the whitespace out by using str.strip. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
myDF = pd.read_csv('Zword.csv')
myDF[myDF['z '] == 'zythum '] # This has the whitespace
myDF['z '] = myDF['z '].map(str.strip)
myDF[myDF['z '] == 'zythum'] # mapped the whitespace away
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the whole column to `str` type:

```py
    words_df['word'] = words_df['word'].astype(str)
```

This should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use this to do the work. Change parameters as required.

````
import glob as glob
import os as os
import csv

def match(dataframe):
    l = []
    for i in dataframe:
        l.append('zythum' in i)
    data = pd.DataFrame(l)
    data.columns = ['word']
    return data

path = r'Word lists in csv/' # use your path
files = os.listdir(path)
li = []
for filename in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(path + filename, index_col=None, header=None, names = ['word'], engine='python', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    li.append(df)
words_df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

words_df[match(words_df['word'])].dropna()```
````